# CardLayout in simple Game doesn't switch the JPanel properly

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

I am working on a remastered version of the game 'Breakout' for my studies and am facing a weird problem:

I have a simple start screen, where the player should be able to type in a name and view the current high scores etc. To start the game I use a CardLayout which should switch to the `gamePanel`. Somehow this doesn't happen, but the game loop gets started and I get the *game Over* Message when the ball leaves the JPanel. Strangely, the `gamePanel` appeares together with the game Over JOptionPane and the switch back to the start screen works properly.  I have searched a lot also on StackOverflow, but none of the solutions that I have found worked for me. Here is my Code:

This is my Game.java, where the main Method is located:

```
public class Game  extends JFrame {
    private static final int width = 1280;
    private static final int height = 720;
    private static final String LOBBY_PANEL = "Lobby Panel";
    private static final String GAME_PANEL = "Game Panel";
    private boolean run = false;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel();
    private LobbyPanel lobbyPanel;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;

    public Game(){
        super("Breakout Remastered");
        cardPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        cardLayout = (CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout();
        lobbyPanel = new LobbyPanel(this);
        gamePanel = new GamePanel(this);
        cardPanel.add(lobbyPanel, LOBBY_PANEL);
        cardPanel.add(gamePanel, GAME_PANEL);
        this.add(cardPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setSize(width, height);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, LOBBY_PANEL);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Game gameFrame = new Game();
            gameFrame.setVisible(true);
        });

    }

    public void playGame() {
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, GAME_PANEL);
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
        this.run = true;

        while (run) {
            gamePanel.move();
            gamePanel.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException iEx) {
                iEx.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopGame() {
        cardLayout.show(cardPanel, LOBBY_PANEL);
        this.run = false;
    }
}
```

This is my GamePanel.java:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private Game game;
    private Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    private Racquet racquet = new Racquet(this);

    public GamePanel(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                racquet.keyPressed(keyEvent);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                racquet.keyReleased(keyEvent);
            }
        };
        addKeyListener(keyListener);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void move() {
        ball.move();
        racquet.move();
    }

    public void reset() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paint(graphics);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        racquet.paint(g2d);
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        game.stopGame();
    }


    public Racquet getRacquet() {
        return racquet;
    }

    public void setRacquet(Racquet racquet) {
         this.racquet = racquet;
    }
}
```

And this is my LobbyPanel.java:

```
public class LobbyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final JLabel labelForUserTextField = new JLabel("Username");
    private JTextField userName = new JTextField("", 20);
    private JButton startButton = new JButton("Play!");
    private JButton highScoreButton = new JButton("View Best");
    private JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    private Game game;

    public LobbyPanel(Game game) {

        startButton.addActionListener(this);

        this.game = game;
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        GridBagConstraints labelConst = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelConst.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3);

        labelConst.gridx = 0;
        labelConst.gridy = 0;
        this.add(labelForUserTextField, labelConst);
        labelConst.gridx = 1;
        this.add(userName, labelConst);
        labelConst.gridx = 0;
        labelConst.gridy = 1;
        this.add(cancelButton, labelConst);
        labelConst.gridx = 1;
        this.add(highScoreButton, labelConst);
        labelConst.gridx = 2;
        this.add(startButton, labelConst);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        try {
            if(actionEvent.getSource() == this.startButton) {
                this.game.playGame();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that someone can figure out why this code doesn't work as expected.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: `public class GamePanel extends JPanel { .. public void paint(Graphics graphics) {` That method should be **`paintComponent(Graphics)`** for any `JComponent` (of which `JPanel` is one).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I would imagine that 95% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [**Minimal**, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: The problem with the minimal example is, that i don't know where exactly the problem is located in my code. Well I can remove the Racquet and Ball calsses from the post, but i don't know which component fails in the other classes.

Comment: Apart from what @AndrewThompson said, you shouldn't use a `while (true)` loop, instead use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and never use a `Thread.sleep(...)` in a Swing application, otherwise it will block the EDT

Comment: *"Well I can remove the Racquet and Ball calsses.."* So you do know, or at least strongly suspect, certain parts are not relevant. Remove them and test that theory! *"i don't know where exactly the problem is located in my code"* Part of the benefit of creating a [mcve] as suggested by @JoeC is that you'll find out! If you can't be bothered putting the effort in to find out, ***why should anyone else?***

Comment: @Frakcool *"you shouldn't use a `while (true)` loop"* Well spotted! Admittedly, I only clanced at the code, which is all I'll tend to do until there is an MCVE, compiled in my IDE, formatted to my tastes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner has made no attempt to debug the application themself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the problem was as mentioned by [Frakcool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180785/frakcool): the `while(true){...` blocked the GUI, so I replaced it with a Thread and now it works.